# Footer снизу

Tags: html, css

Код:

```
<body>
          <div id="container">
               <div id="header">
                    <div id="money"></div>
                    <div id="bumial"></div>
                    <div id="news"></div>
               </div>
               <div id="sitebar">
                    <div id="razdel"></div>
                    <ul id="menu"></ul>
               </div>
               <div id="content">
                    <div id="kotel">
                        <div id="txt"></div>
                    </div>
               </div>
               <div id="polezn">
                     <div id="poleznoe"></div>
                     <ul id="pmenu"></ul>
               </div>
                <div class="content1"></div>
          </div>
        <div id="footer">
        <p>©All right reserved.</p>
        </div>
     </body>
```

Проблема такова. Абсолютно никаким способом не получается прижать футер к низу, решил проблему для себя, сделать футер частью контета отступив немного вниз. В чём может быть проблема? Возможно ли, что в файле css указал то, что мешает его прижать к низу. Спасибо.

Comment: [Поиск работает][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/search/?q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83&t=question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

body {height: 100%; padding-bottom: 100px;}
 #footer{ height: 100px; margin-top: -100px; }

Comment: Футер прижимается к низу страницы, маленькой размером. Если  страница больше, то футер так и остаётся стоять на месте.

Answer (score 0):

Я пользуюсь таким вариантом:

```
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content">
        </div>
        <div id="side">
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
<div id="footer">
</div>

html, body {height: 100%;}

#wrap {min-height: 100%;}

#main {overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 150px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;}

/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:0;
    margin-top:-32767px;/
}
```

Источник http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html